# Why is printf in NASM assembly 64 bit returning -nan?

Tags: assembly, printf, nasm, x86-64

All I am trying to do is print a floating point number using the printf function.  When it is run, it outputs : 
The floating point number is -nan

Why is it not outputting the floating point number stored (5.93)?

```
%macro EXITPGM 0
mov eax, 0
call exit
%endmacro

section .data
        flt1  dq 0.0
        msg db "The floating point number is %f",10,0



section .text
        global main
        extern printf
        extern exit

main:
        push rbp
        mov qword[flt1], __float64__(5.93)
        mov rdi, msg
        mov rax, 1
        movq xmm0, qword [flt1]
        call printf



        pop rbp
        EXITPGM
```

Comment: There is no `mov mem, imm64` instruction. My version of `nasm` produces the following: `warning: signed dword immediate exceeds bounds`. That means it truncated your 64 bits to 32.

Comment: Why don't you just `flt1: dq 5.93` like a normal person?  Or `mov rax, imm64` and `movq xmm0, rax` if you want to get an immediate into an XMM registers.

Comment: If I use float32, it returns: The floating point number is 0.000000

Comment: Because `printf` still expects a double. Do what Peter said: `mov rax, __float64__(5.93); mov [flt1], rax`.

Comment: Because I need to be able to move an immediate value to the variable that is defined (flt1)

Comment: That worked; thank you!

Comment: @PeterCordes: "*like a normal person*"? Normal persons don't program, and certainly not in assembler. ;-)

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: ok fine, I admit I'm not normal :)

Comment: @PeterCordes: neither am I, I guess. A programming dentist. <g>